# Why constexpr data members are not implicitly static?

Tags: c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr

if you do this:

```
constexpr int LEN = 100;
```

`LEN` variable defined as `const` without need of typing `const` keyword.
It also have `static` storage, without need to type `static` keyword.

From the other hand, if we do same in `class`:

```
struct A{
   constexpr static int SIZE = 100;
};
```

`SIZE` is still defined as `const` without need of typing const keyword,

However `SIZE` is not `static` data member.
You need to type `static` explicitly. If you don't there will be compilation error.

**Question is:

What is the reason of need to explicitly type `static`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constexpr` should not imply `static`, because having `constexpr`
without `static` makes sense. Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Dim
{
    constexpr Dim(int a,int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    constexpr int Prod() const { return a*b; }
    int a,b;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr Dim sz(3,4);
    int arr[ sz.Prod() ];
    std::cout << sizeof(arr) << std::endl;
}
```

It should also not imply `static` outside of class definition
since `static` there means 'local to translation unit' and `constexpr`
does not require that.

Comment: At namespace scope, `constexpr` doesn't quite imply `static`, but it comes close. It implies `const`, and namespace-scope non-volatile `const` variables have internal linkage (i.e., are `static`) by default.

Comment: can you have volatile const variables?

Comment: @soandos: sure, you are not allowed to change them, but the program need to read them every time, since the hardware might change the value. (for example)

Answer (score 3):

`static` doesn't have same signification in both context :

- for `LEN`, `static` means "only available in this compilation unit", so only internal linkage. It's a `storage specifier`
- for `A::SIZE`, `static` means "it's a class member", so not bound to specific instances

`constexpr` in class context can refer to instance or class member or function, so compiler can't determine at your place if it's `static` or not, *ie* bound or not to a specific instance. It's same reasoning as `const` specifier. But, as you can imagine, it's a non-sense to have a non-static `constexpr` member, so it's forbidden. Example :

```
class A
{
     int a;
     constexpr A(int value): a(value) {}

     // constexpr bound to a specific instance
     constexpr int getDouble() const
     {     return a*2;    }

     // constexpr not bound to a specific instance
     static constexpr int getDouble(int b)
     {     return b*2;    }
}
```

`constexpr` in global context refers to something which will be calculated at compile time (or, for function, if not possible to calculate at compile time, which will be inlined), so no need of external linkage and so, comparable behavior as a `static` global variable or function (only comparable because, with compile time calculation or inlining, you also don't need internal linkage)

```
constexpr int a = 5; // Will be replace everywhere by value

/* If b is constexpr, calcul are done at compile time and result will be used
* else double is inlined, so no need of linkage at all
*/
constexpr int getDouble(int b)  
{     return b * 2;     }
```

Comment: You can't call a function "double" (it's a keyword) and you can't have non-static constexpr data members in a class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about what `static` means at global scope, and your question is based on that misunderstanding.

> `LEN` variable defined as const without need of typing `const` keyword.

Of course `constexpr` implies `const`, that shouldn't be surprising.

> It also have `static` storage, without need to type `static` keyword.

N.B. a global variable **always has static storage**, because its lifetime is global. Adding the `static` keyword does not change that, what it does is give it *internal linkage* meaning it is not accessible by name outside the current translation unit.

That's the same rule for `constexpr` and `const` on global variables: a namespace-scope const variable implicitly has internal linkage (which is one of the many meanings of "static").

But a class-scope const variable does not have internal linkage, **even if you add `static` to it**. Marking a variable `static` means something completely different at namespace-scope and class-scope. It doesn't make sense to automatically add `static` to class members marked `const` or `constexpr` because that would mean something completely different than it does to variables at namespace-scope.

So `constexpr` implies `const` (obviously), and at namespace scope `const` implies internal linkage.

At class scope `constexpr` still implies `const`, but that doesn't have any effect on whether a member variable is a "class variable" or an "instance variable".

Comment: downvoted, his question although badly phrased makes sense. If something is constexpr member (initialized at compile time and known at compile time) it makes no sense to make it an instance variable instead of class variable. Since it is idiotic to have instances store same value that never changes. In fact if you miss static code will not compile(meaning it has no other meaning): error: non-static data member 'SIZE' declared 'constexpr'
    constexpr int SIZE = 100;